# How change jndi remote lookup to local lookup in jboss 6.0.0

Tags: java, jndi, ejb-2.x

I am going through the Permormace activity of our project. This project has been deployed in JBOSS 6.0.0. Presenlty communication between EJBs using remote JNDI lookup using within the same container which is not required and it taking time. So I woul like to convrt remote JNDI lookup to local JNDI lookup. Will it work? Please explain who to convert remote JNDI lookup to local JNDI.

Or please suggest the other technique to over come this issue so I can improve our application performace.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the client which is using your `EJB` is in the same Jboss or use `Remote` if client which is using `EJB's` is on different Jboss.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Client is on same JBOSS server

Comment: Then it will work fine.  Generally if client is on same machine never expose remote interfaces as they are never needed.

Comment: Amit, do you have any link that help me out to change the remote jndi lookup to local jndi lookup as my project havent exposed any local interfaces.

Comment: It has been long since I have worked on EJB 2.1 but I guess [this](http://www.learntechnology.net/content/ejb/ejb2_1.jsp) will help you.

Comment: I am glad, I didn't have to work with pre `EJB3`. Looks horrible.

Comment: @PetarMinchev missed pre :(. Yup EJB3 World is far easy than Ejb2.x